# How to display all the files in a directory which contains a word a certain number of times?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I currently use this command `find -name "*.xml" | xargs grep -c -H -w "word"` to display all the XML files in a directory which contains a specific word and how many times. It works quite well (because the word I search appears only once per line, if it wasn't the case I should find another solution because of grep) :

```bash
./file1.xml:2
./file2.xml:3
./file3.xml:6
```

but what is really interesting for me is to **only display words with the more word matching**.

Anyone knows how to filter this output with only the files with the highest scores ?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe to `awk` to compare the counts with the minimum.

```
find -name "*.xml" | xargs grep -c -H -w "word" | awk -F: '$NF > 3'
```

Comment: Simple and efficient ! Thx m8 !

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`, this can be done without resorting to `find` and `xargs`:

```
grep -rHcw --include='*.xml' "word" . | awk -F: '$NF>2'
```

It is also possible to order the output by occurrence count :

```
grep -rHcw --include='*.txt' "word" . |
    sed 's/.*:\(.*\)/\1 &/' |
    sort -n |
    sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner to do it all in one if you can. `awk` can handle that alone, more efficiently.

```
$: grep -cHw word ?.xml */?.xml # these ae the files we'll scan for a's
a.xml:4
b.xml:2
c.xml:0
foo/d.xml:1
```

First, you *could* use `shopt -s globstar` and pass your file list as `**/*.xml`, but there are some possible issues - then again, you aren't telling `find` to only give you *files*, either...

If you are just trying to find the file with the MOST hits,

```
$: awk '/\<word\>/{hits[FILENAME]++} END{ for (f in hits) { if (hits[f] > max) { max = hits[f]; file=f } } print file":"max }' ?.xml */?.xml
a:4
```

...but if you just want the most hits, and don't want to use `awk` -

```
find -name "*.xml" | xargs grep -cHw "word" | sort -t: -k2,2r | head -1
```

If you're doing that, you should probably use `-type f` -

```
find -name "*.xml" -type f | xargs grep -cHw word | sort -t: -k2,2r | head -1
```

You *could* use

```
find -name "*.xml" -type f -exec grep -cHw word {} \; | sort -t: -k2,2r | head -1
```

but in this case I think maybe `xargs` *might* manage to spawn fewer total processes, though it may not matter much unless there's a LOT of files.

If what you want is files with more than a certain minimum number of hits -

```
$: awk -v min=3 '/\<word\>/{ if (++cnt >= min) { print FILENAME": "min" or more"; cnt=0; nextfile; } }' ?.xml */?.xml 
a: 3 or more

$: awk -v min=2 '/\<word\>/{ if (++cnt >= min) { print FILENAME": "min" or more"; cnt=0; nextfile; } }' ?.xml */?.xml
a: 2 or more
b: 2 or more
```

This also lets you easily check only specific columns, control exactly what output you want, short-circuit out early on large files if you like, scan multiple patterns and give each one differing behavior, do BEGIN setup or END summary processing, and a lot more. You just have to understand `awk` a bit and write the logic in as much or as little detail as you need.

If `-type f` doesn't really matter, try `shopt -s globstar` to pass indeterminate depth of subdirectories with `**`. For more exactly the same output as the find solution, use `./**/*.xml`

```
$: shopt -s globstar
$: awk -v min=2 '/\<word\>/{ if (++cnt >= min) { print FILENAME": "min" or more"; cnt=0; nextfile; } }' ./**/*.xml
./a.xml: 2 or more
./b.xml: 2 or more

$: awk '/\<word\>/{hits[FILENAME]++} END{ for (f in hits) { if (hits[f] > max) { max = hits[f]; file=f } } print file":"max }' ./**/*.xml
./a.xml:4
```

One process, instead of four for a *find|xargs|sort|head* pipeline.

Comment: You should mention that you'd need GNU awk (or similar?) for `\<` and `\>` word boundaries as they aren't POSIX.

Comment: Excellent point. POSIX `\b` should work, though... c.f. [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think `\b` is POSIX either. `\b` has a meaning at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05 but I don't see any meaning for it or any word boundary reference at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04.

Comment: Huh! Thanks for pointing that out! Always test your patterns to make sure they do what you want, lol... [`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#posix) don't seem to work in my `grep` or `awk` or `sed` either. `[^[:alnum:]]` seems a poor and very situational substitute...

Comment: Right, it's a problem! I tend to use `(^|[^[:alnum:]_]|$)` if I want to be POSIX compliant but then you end up with the character before/after the string you actually want being part of the match, if it exists, so you need to do additional processing and if you want to match globally using word boundaries in input like `x.foo.bar.y` then it's even worse as each `.` is consumed by the end of the first match and so isn't available for the start of the second (I know there's an alternative regexp in THIS case). I tend to give up on POSIX at that point and just say "using GNU awk..." :-).